# How to get the containing grids key from within the server side DataBinding event of a RadComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, telerik, radcombobox

I'm trying to uniquely set the radcombobox datasource based on the detail grid ID value.  I would like different values in the comboboxes for each detail table view.

here is the server side event code:

```
protected void MethodRadComboBox_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)sender;
combo.DataSource = ...need key of details GridTableView DataKey value in order to set the source
}


                        <CommandItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="MethodRadComboBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                AllowCustomText="true"
                                EmptyMessage="Select a Method."
                                DataTextField="MethodName" DataValueField="MethodName"
                                AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                OnDataBinding="MethodRadComboBox_DataBinding"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="MethodRadComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>

                        </CommandItemTemplate>
                        <Columns>
```

Comment: I've correcty formatted your code

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly your question. Are you trying to set the grid as datasource of your combobox? Please explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i need the id of the detail grid so i can select the correct items to set the datasource of the radcombobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridCommandItem)
    {
        GridCommandItem commandItem = (GridCommandItem)e.Item;
        RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)commandItem.FindControl("MethodRadComboBox");
        combo.DataSource = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataSource;
        combo.DataBind();
```